# GCP DataPrep - Unable to rename output files Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow, google-cloud-dataprep

I have created simple dataprep workflow(Source File as CSV from GCS, simple transformation(Upper case conversion) & Target - load into BigQuery).

When i run this workflow job in DataPrep UI, I am getting error as:

> Unable to rename output files from
> gs://******test/*******/temp/dax-tmp-2021-04-02_09_21_11-16351772716646701863-S07-0-d007cba17fe923f9/tmp-d007cba17fe92b44@DAX.ism to gs://*******test/*******/temp/tmp-d007cba17fe92b44@*.ism.,

**I am having below IAM roles:**

Dataprep User,
Storage Admin,
Storage Object Admin,
Storage Object Creator,
Viewer

Since i already have admin access in GCS, i am not sure why i am getting 'Unable to rename output files' error. But i am able to modify files are available in GCS using gsutil command.

Kindly advise whether this is access issue in DataPrep and how to solve this problem.

**DataPrep Logs**:
[image: DataPrep Logs]

**DataFlow Log**:
[image: DataFlow Log]

Comment: I know I am very late to this question, but anyone who is looking at this question will find this helpful.
This issue on your transforms or earlier steps on your beam job, in my case I was reading from PubSub and parsing the GCS file, reading the data of that file, and loading it into bigquery.

My ParDo function for parsing the GCS file was not having proper bigquery column names and there was a schema mismatch that was causing this error (which was totally unrelated)